# Customize TFS workitem screen

Tags: tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

This is related to TFS2010
I have the following requirment:

Multiple tasks can be associated with a user story 
when a user story is closed using the VSTS UI, I need to check if all the associated tasks are closed as well.

My Question:

Is it possible to bind a validation function to workitem UI?

will witadmin be of use in this case?

Comment: Downvoted, your question is not clear to me, probably due to the difficult to interpret language usage.

Comment: well my question was upvoted and was even responded by a member. wonder if your reason is sufficient enough to downvote.

Comment: @kroonwijk: Feel free to ask the author what the intention of his question was. Therefore we can write comments.

Comment: You are right, I will do that. @balalakshmi: sorry about the downvote, will retract it (if possible?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

witadmin is used to administer your work item templates, not for editing them.

Your requirement cannot be fulfilled with a simple work item template. I think you have to create a query to select all tasks that are not closed but have a closed user story.

Another way is to create a TFS addon. A similar task has beed described [here](http://www.techques.com/question/1-5156090/TFS-Execute-Custom-Code-on-a-Work-Item-Transition).